# Connecting Windows VPN thought Asus RT-N16 to my client Office VPN fail

Tags: networking, router, vpn

i'm having a problem with my brand new Asus RT-N16 Router.

I cannot  connect my Windows VPN to any of my client VPN. It keep failling telling me: "A connection to the remote computer could not be established, so the port used for this connection was closed"`

But if i plug my modem directly to my laptop, bypassing the router, the VPN work perfectly.

Can someone help me on this?

Note that i'm not talking about le router Build-in VPN server or client, but the Windows client VPN connection.

Thanks

Hugo

EDIT:
I've try to use the Build-in VPN Client from the Router, end this is the log that it give me

```
r  2 15:18:17 pptp[620]: pppd 2.4.7 started by admin, uid 0
Mar  2 15:18:18 pptp[620]: Connect: ppp5 <--> pptp (###.###.###.###)
Mar  2 15:18:48 pptp[620]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Mar  2 15:18:48 pptp[620]: Connection terminated.
Mar  2 15:18:48 pptp[620]: Modem hangup
```

Comment: I've talk to the Asus tech guy, and he tell me that the problem came from the IP Scope that me ISP give me scope is "172.27.#.#".

Comment: I've try the same router on another ISP, and the VPN is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  finally found the trouble.
In between my Router and my Modem, there is my Telo Ooma IP Phone system, and he was the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your ISP is not assigning a public IP address to the router, in your comments you mentioned that your IP address is a 172.27.x.x which is in private IP space and is not public space, meaning it is likely a NAT connection from your ISPs public IP to your router's private IP address which is likely blocking inbound VPN connections. The best solution would be to get a static public IP assigned to your connection.

It is also possible that your ISP modem is doing the NAT translation and you need to put it in "bridge mode" or something similar to pass the public IP through to the router, best to contact your ISP for details.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to enable VPN Passthrough.

See the "WAN – NAT Passthrough" section on the following site: http://nextgendigitalhome.com/the-asus-rt-n16-router-firmware-part-4-advanced-wan-settings/

Comment: I've review the config from the "WAN - NET Passthrough", disabled all setting reenabled all, reboot the router, still dont' work. and get the sme error

Comment: Added question details

Comment: Is my public Address " 172.27.#.#" may have something to do with the problem?